# Is there any way to add through to M2M field with keeping the related manager's .add() working?

Tags: python, django, orm

While Django doesn't completely support adding the `through` attribute to a M2M field (in order to add some extra fields), it can be migrated. The main issue is, Django [will complain when any code tries to `.add()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/548f78ba46efff5aa3613fc4d7f86c9166d349e4/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L912) models to the related set even if there are no required fields in the `through` model outside of the FKs of the linked models.

So, I want to add a nullable field to the `through` model and still keep `.add()` and `remove` working like it was before (and implicitely using `None` as the nullable field value). Adding `auto_created=True` in the meta almost works, but it breaks migrations amongst other things. Is there any way to make it work outside of overriding the many2many descriptor (which isn't exactly included in the public API, though a lot of third-party Django packages use it)?

Comment: FYI, this issue is tracked [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9475).

Comment: Thanks, I guess it means 'yes, with a custom manytomany field with a patched descriptor'.